# Triangle artifacts in cycles render with material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I have used the same camera, world and material for renders with a previous, similarly-modeled mesh.  The renders had no artifacts. All faces, curves, interior of the holes etc were smooth.

But when I try the same camera, world and material with my current mesh, this is the result.
[image: problematic model view with normals][image]

I started each of these with an SVG curve of the profile of the item, converting it to a mesh and extruding it to the appropriate Z height.  However, I think with the successful model, I had first subdivided the mesh into quads after converting from a curve.  I forgot this step with the pictured mesh above, and have tried to clean up as best I can.

Any suggestions for how to clean this up without having to just start over?

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: Your mesh seems to have very large NGons, and an uneven topology with very dense areas with lots of very small polygons that then cause lots of thin and long triangles on the larger faces. That is possibly what is causing those artifacts but it's hard to tell without a closer looking at the file. Could you post a link to the Blend file? You may also try recalculating normals and removing doubles to see if it helps somehwat

Comment: Sorry, probably should have mentioned that I don't feel I'd be cleared to share the .blend file for this. The ngon issue makes sense. I did try removing doubles and recalculating normals a few times while finding holes in the mesh along the way.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. With the cleanup required, I might save time just starting with a new profile curve->mesh with better quads before extruding.

Comment: Yeah, I started some cleanup on the existing mesh guided with your suggestions, and the renders were getting better.  But there were so many that I just opted to go with starting again and extruding off a better mesh profile.  Removed, optimized some vertices on the curve, converted to mesh then split into quads.  

Checking renders as I go, punching the holes with booleans, and it's going much quicker, no cleanup required.  Thanks a million!