# How to automatically create faces between a set of vertices

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I have the following object with an inner screw-like cylinder, and an outer hexagonal prism:

[image]

I am trying to close this shape up by adding faces between the screw and the hexagon, to create a nut for 3d printing, essentially. But, as you can see, there are almost a hundred vertices on the screw. Is there any way to close this shape up automatically? I don't care about the topology of the model too much, as this will be 3d printed.

Comment: Try bridge edge loops. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80310/merging-two-faces/80324#80324